# Lua - nils in table constructor

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a following code:

```
local ta = { nil, nil, nil, 1, a = 2 }
local tb = { [4] = 1, a = 2 }

for i = 1, #ta do
  print('ta['..i..']= ', ta[i])
end
for i = 1, #tb do
  print('tb['..i..']= ', tb[i])
end
```

And get the following output:

```
ta[1]=  nil
ta[2]=  nil
ta[3]=  nil
ta[4]=  1
```

I assumed that both tables should be the same. But it's not quite.

I try create table with empty constructor, and initialize elements one by one, including nils at the beginning. But got the same result with the table tb.

What the difference?
Can I manage this manually?

Comment: Both tables are the same.  But `#` operator may behave strange on tables with `nil`s inside.

Comment: Is nil is not identical to the absence element?

Comment: Can I reset size to real without walking the table?

Comment: `nil` is identical to the absence of element.  But "size" of such tables is not defined in Lua.  You must not apply operator `#` to tables with `nil`s inside.

Comment: What is it that you're _actually_ trying to achieve? What's the purpose of what you're doing? Iterate over all elements? Or numer of elements in a table once the array chain is broken?

Comment: I write a simple function which converts lua values to string, containing lua code.  
To make string more readable and compact, at first I iterate table with `for` from 1 to #t, and only then use `for in` for all other elements.  

For example `{1, 2, nil, 4}` ==> `"{1,2,[4]=4}"`.  

In most cases all works fine, but sometimes i get something like `"{nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,10}"`.  

I just want to understand, how to fix it in simplest way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While W.B. is mostly right, in that the length operator is not very consistent for arrays with holes, it's not undefined either.

The length of a table is defined in the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) to be "any integer index `n` such that `t[n]` is not `nil` and `t[n+1]` is nil; moreover, if `t[1]` is `nil`, `n` can be zero."

This means that the length of `{"a", nil, "b", nil, "c"}` can be either 1, 3, or 5. So while the length operator will no longer give you a very useful and specific result, it won't give you garbage either.

Comment: To me, that's "undefined". The result depends on more than the current set of key-value pairs in the table. It depends on previous operations on the table (and on the implementation). Two tables with the same set of key-value pairs can have different "lengths".

Comment: From the C programmer angle, if the length of an array with holes were truly undefined, then the length of the array `{1,2,nil,4}` could be 4, or 2, or 0, or 9001, or "banana". Really, the result could be anything. By defining the behavior of the length operator to account for arrays with holes, Lua ensures that such results cannot happen.

Comment: For a Lua table whose current key-value pairs are equivalent to **{1, nil, 3, nil, 5}, the length operator can return any one of 1, 3 or 5**. Yes, there is a rule about possible results, but the single specific result is not defined. Ultimately, [whenever an operation needs the the length of a table, the table should be a proper sequence or have a __len metamethod](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.5). (A sequence is [a table where the set of all positive numeric keys is equal to {1..n} for some integer n](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.1).)

Comment: "Any one of 1, 3, or 5" is more specific than "completely undefined". Yes, I agree with you that arrays with holes aren't that useful, due to these quirks with the length operator and table operations, but IMO saying that the behavior is completely undefined is misleading.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo you can **always** define something undefined as defined. If I defined a behaviour of a function to return _4, 2, or 0, or 9001, or "banana", or a random number, or blowing up your monitor_, would it be defined then? How does it change usefulness of it? It is defined as to stability of your application, by it is not defined in terms of its usefulness. You use that operator when you don't know the length of the table. After using it, you still don't know it, because it returns a random number out of a limited (but most likely unknown to you) set.

Comment: @W.B. Yes, it would be defined, because you just defined it to be any of those results. _Which_ result it gives is undefined. (In comparison, `malloc` returns an address that you can use to store values in. _Which_ address it returns is undefined). I already said that I agree that using the length operator on arrays with holes isn't very useful, but that's not what I'm arguing. I simply wanted to point out that the length operator isn't completely undefined for arrays with holes, and won't return garbage if you try it.

Comment: The result could be useful. For example, I may have a table where I'd like to store an arbitrary number of objects & be able to iterate over them. I'd like to interface with this collection with a malloc/free interface. function malloc(tbl) local idx = #tbl; tbl[idx] = 0; return idx end function free(tbl, idx) tbl[idx] = nil end. This will never result in me overwriting an index in the table with a non nil value

Answer (score 7):

In Lua the behaviour of length operator `#` is undefined for arrays, where sequence is broken, that is, it doesn't start at 1 or has empty slots inside.

Comment: Seems to be true. Earlier I thought that `#` return length of longest series not nil elements, starting from 1 index.

Answer (score 4):

Use ipairs() to handle the array part and keep track of the last index you processed. Then you can use pairs() to process the rest of the elements.

```
-- The array part. This loop will stop when it reaches a nil array element.
local length = 0
for key, value in ipairs(t) do
  length = key
  -- Process it.
end

-- The hash part.
for key, value in pairs(t) do
  -- Check if the key is in the array we already processed.
  if type(key) ~= 'number' or key < 1 or key > length or key ~= math.floor(key) then
    -- Process it.
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please consider taking the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learning more about how to [write great answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  One way to make this a better answer would be to demonstrate the use of the functions you mention with actual code.

Comment: Thanks. I've added an example.

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer to
`local i = 1
while x[i] ~= nil do
  ...
  i = i + 1
end
 
for k,v in pairs(x) do
   if type(k) ~= 'number' or k >= i or k < 1 or k ~= math.floor(k) then
    ...
  end
end` for performance reasons.